# Check if two adjoined elements are ordered using reduceLeft

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have an exercise to check if two adjoined elements are ordered using **sliding,map,reduceLeft**. For example:

```
val seq1 = Seq(1,2,2,4)
isOrdered(seq1)(_ < _) == false
isOrdered(seq1)(_ <= _) == true


def isOrdered[A](seq: Seq[A])(leq: (A,A) => Boolean): Boolean = { 

}
```

honestly I don't know what to start with.

Comment: ok, my first idea is to use sliding(2), so I have List(List(1,2), List(2,2), List(2,4)) but how to compare them now?

Comment: I also tried to flat one List, so I'd like to have tuple: List((1,2),(2,2),(2,4)) using:
`val seq= Seq(1,2,2,4)
  val seqSlided = seq.sliding(2).toSeq
  val seqTupled = seqSlided match {
    case List(a,b)::rest => (a,b)::rest
   

  }`
but my result is List((1,2), List(2,2), List(2,4)) so it works only for the first inside List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can do it using those three operations:

```
def isOrdered[A](seq: Seq[A])(leq: (A, A) => Boolean): Boolean =
  seq
    .sliding(2)
    .map { case e1 :: e2 :: Nil => leq(e1, e2) }
    .reduceLeft(_ && _)
```

First we divide the sequence into groups of two consecutive elements using sliding. Then we apply `leq` on each pair (in other words, we map each two-element list into result of `leq` on those two elements). Lastly, we reduce the result sequence of Booleans into a single Boolean with a logical AND, meaning that our predicate needs to hold for all values.

```
val seq1 = Seq(1, 2, 2, 4)

val less: (Int, Int) => Boolean = _ < _
val lessOrEqual: (Int, Int) => Boolean = _ <= _

isOrdered(seq1)(less) // false
isOrdered(seq1)(lessOrEqual) // true
```

There are some unsafety concerns here:

1. If you have a one-element sequence, the sliding operation will produce an iterator over a single-list element, and the pattern matching will fail.
2. If you have an empty sequence, reduce will explode.

Comment: I'm a bit confused how the reduce works there. Let's say: we use "less", so after first check we have True, because 1<2. What happens then, when we get into reduceLeft? I don't see it :/

Comment: After map operations we have (true, false, true), don't we? So what does reduce do now?

Comment: Once we reach the reduce phase, we have a sequence of booleans - one for each pair (e.g. for `(1, 2, 3)` you'd have two booleans: `(1 < 2,  2 < 3)`). So what we reduce is a bunch of booleans into a single boolean, and this is done via `_ && _` operation. It's shorthand for `(a: Boolean, b: Boolean) => a && b`. Are you familiar with how reduce works in general? It will take first two elements and apply the function to them, then to that result + next elem, then again result + next elem, and so on. If at any point we get a false, the whole thing will become false.

Comment: > After map operations we have (true, false, true), don't we? So what does reduce do now?

Yes, exactly! Now you just need to learn how reduce / fold works (hint: difference is that fold has an initial element, reduce doesn't). Googling "reduce Scala" should get you far, and Scaladoc is good as well.

Comment: Generally I can imagine how, but maybe you'd just confirm if I think well.
Having Seq(1,2,2,4). We have (1,2) [true], (2,2) [false], (2,4) [true]. 
We are reducing so: 1. true && false = false (result)
2. result && true = false (final result)

Having Seq(6,4,2,1) (6,4) [false], (4,2) [false], (2,1) [false]
false && false = false (result)
result && false = false (final result)

Is it ok?

Comment: I have one more question: Why when you are using map, you don't use () and you use {} and also, why don't you do it e1::e2, but you add second :: and writing Nil?

Comment: Simplest answer for () vs {} is that I would normally prefer (), but I had to use {} here because I had a partial function (using `case`). This is one of rare things in Scala syntax that I dislike and I wish I could explain more simply. Second question is easier - because of `head :: tail` nature of Lists. With `e1 :: e2 :: Nil`, the pattern matching recognizes the list as `List(e1, e2, theRest)` (with theRest being empty list), and with `e1 :: e2` it would be recognized as `List(e1, theRest)`. Instead of matching first two elements, I would match the first element and the rest of the list.

Comment: why is theRest empty list? When we take first two elements, for example: (1,2), the rest is not empty. Does the case make theRest empty? I don't understand why it is recognized as empty list, when there are elements left

Comment: theRest is empty because after sliding, we have a List of many small 2-element lists [1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 4], and when we map, we pattern match on each of them one by one

Comment: so if we pattern them one by one, wouldn't `e1::e2::rest` mean, that we take [1,2] and [2,2] and theRest would be [2,4]?
On the other hand if you say that we have a List of many small 2-element lists, why do we have to add this third parameter (::Nil). I still don't get it and when I try to print it, I get as a result "<iterator>" so I can't even see that myself.

Comment: Add `.toList` to <iterator> and you'll see it yourself. After doing sliding(2), we produce a list of lists, and then we modify each element of the outer list (by mapping), which means we modify each inner two-element list. And how do we modify it? It's of the format [e1, e2], so we pattern match on it to extract those elements and work with them. Note that after we did sliding(2), we know that each inner list is a two-element list, so we match using e1 :: e2 :: Nil. It would work just the same if we said e1 :: e2 :: whatever, but the former is more specific.

Comment: ok, so if we can write "whatever" I do understand now :) I just didn't know what you write ::Nil, when theRest is not Nil, there are two lists left, that's what I didn't understand- why you used ::Nil and how it understands it :)

Comment: or I will add one more question:
If we have list of lists so when we map, we take each of the inner lists so for example we take List(1,2), and we pattern THIS List, so if we do e1::e2 it should understand it like e1 = 1 and e2 = 2 (e2 is a one-element tail) so why do we have to use this second :: ? I don't get it. When I was patterning the Lists, I've always used only head::tail and it worked.

Comment: No, I don't think you fully got it yet :) But we are close. There is no rest. At that point, you have many lists, each one has only two elements. Because we did sliding(2). So if we said e1 :: e2 :: whatever, we are just being more flexible on `whatever`, but in practice it will always be e1 :: e2 :: empty list anyway. It would be easier to continue this discussion somewhere else, and SO will probably warn us about the same soon due to many comments. It will be much easier if I can show some formatted code (the formatting in these comments is not good). Can we talk on gitter?

Comment: > I don't get it. 
No worries, I think this is a more general discussion than just ordering adjoined elements :) I'm happy to help and show you how things work in Scala, but please let's move the discussion outside of this format because it's really difficult to work without proper formatting and with limited characters etc

Comment: ok, thank you, then let me know where to go in gitter, as I've never used it

Comment: make an account and seach for "slouc"

Comment: I wrote to you, don't know if in good place

Answer (score 3):

"using **sliding,map,reduce**"

```
def isOrdered[A](seq: Seq[A])(pred: (A,A) => Boolean): Boolean =
  seq.sliding(2)
     .map{case Seq(a,b) => pred(a,b)}
     .reduce(_ && _)
```

Note: Not safe for sequences smaller than 2 elements.

Comment: `reduce()` takes all the `Boolean` results from the `map()` operation and reduces them to a single `Boolean` result.

Comment: I know but I don't know how it works for e.g. (false, false, false) when having all the and's false && false = true, so what then?

Comment: `reduce()` takes the first 2 elements and combines them (according to the given operation). It then takes that result and combines it with the next element. This continues until it runs out of next elements to combine with the previous result.

Answer (score 2):

One approach includes `forall`, where `leq: (A,A) => Boolean` must hold for each and every element,

```
def isOrdered[A](seq: Seq[A])(leq: (A,A) => Boolean): Boolean = {
  seq.sliding(2).forall { case(Seq(l,r)) => leq(l,r) }
}
```

Thus for `val seq1 = Seq(1,2,2,4)`,

```
scala> isOrdered(seq1)(_<_)
val res5: Boolean = false

scala> isOrdered(seq1)(_<=_)
val res6: Boolean = true
```